# What is a Node in OpenText LiveLink?

Tags: nodes, opentext, livelink

What is a Node in LiveLink?

Most of the time I worked with LiveLink, they are using Node many time.

What is a Node object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Livelink Node* is an object managed by the [Livelink ECM Server](http://www.opentext.com/2/global/products/products-opentext-ecm-suite.htm). A particular document, folder, e-mail, project, task, discussion that you created in Livelink are Livelink nodes. If you want to browse objects in your system you usually start in a built-in root container - Enterprise Workspace or Personal Workspace and then you go on the path of folders to your document, for example.

Now we come to the reason for the term *node*. Livelink organizes objects in a hierarchy that can be represented as a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure) in computer science. A [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure) consists of [nodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_%28computer_science%29). Nodes can be [*containers (branches)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_node#Terminology) and [*terminals (leaves)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_node#Terminology) while the whole tree starts with a [*root node*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_node#Terminology). The nodes are connected by parent child relation - just like in a file system; only Livelink has many more *node types*; not only folders and files. If you wanted to create a new node type you would see that the API publishes a class `LLNode` which you would inherit from to define features and behavior of your special nodes.

So, a Livelink node is an existing object instance that you created in some container; what the others would call document or other object according to their business scenario. Object hierarchy managed by Livelink is called a tree of nodes often by Livelink developers and administrators.

--- Ferda

Answer (score 1):

Just to add up to Ferdinand Prantl's answer, you can find a list of most node types there: http://www.rssd.esa.int/llinksupport/adminhelp/webadmin/ot_ini-nodetypemap.html

Also, if you want some great resources about development around Livelink, stop by http://www.greggriffiths.org/.

Don't forget to search or ask on the Knowledge Center (you should have access to), http://knowledge.opentext.com/. It can be hard to find rdocumentation on how to use the existing APIs or Web service, but doing so the right way really helps performances (both serverside and clientside).